# Оператор И (&&) в JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, операторы

Здравствуйте. Нужна ваша помощь, мне при нажатии на ссылку:

```
<a id="f1" href="#">Текст</a>
```

Нужно взять все элементы которые я указал ниже, скрыть их и показать элемент с id="f11".

У меня это получилось сделать, но мне нужно оптимизировать код, я использовал логический оператор И (&&), но так как я только начал изучать JQuery у меня оптимизированный вариант не работает.

Вот старый код, который работает:

```
$('#f1').click(function(){
          $('#f9').hide(0,function() {
              $('#f22').hide(0,function() {
                  $('#f33').hide(0,function() {
                      $('#f44').hide(0,function() {
                          $('#f55').hide(0,function() {
                              $('#f66').hide(0,function() {
                                  $('#f77').hide(0,function() {
                                      $('#f88').hide(0,function() {
                                           $('#f11').show(0);
                                          });
                                      });
                                  });
                              });
                          });
                      });
                  });
              });
          });
```

А это новый "оптимизированный" код, который не работает:

```
$('#f1').click(function(){
            $('#f9'&&'#f22'&&'f33'&&'f44'&&'f55'&&'f66'&&'f77'&&'f88').hide(0,function() {
                $('#f11').show(0);
            });
        });
```

И ещё одно, у меня код исполняется при нажатии на ссылку с id="f1", а нужно при нажатии id="f1" или id="f111".

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: `$('#f9, #f22, #f33, #f44, ...')`

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии не только на ссылку id="f1" а ещё и на id="f111" ? Насколько знаю, то это оператор или (||) но как правильно мне написать в моём коде?

Comment: указать селекторы через запятую можно. А вы уверенны что нельзя легче? может приведете пример html можно посмотреть от чего зависят элементы и не делать таких долгих перечислений.

Comment: @Abmin - "... пришлось молча проглотить тот факт, что кто-то неспособен продолжать с этого места сам, прыжком воображения." Форестер "Лейтенант Хорнблауэр" - `$('#f1, #f111').click`

Comment: Способен, причина в том что не работает так  $('#f1, #f111') я тоже думал что будет работать. Выложил весь код [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/a49334tw/)

Comment: Думаю это связано с тем, что элементы с id f111 по id f888 находятся в блоке с id="f9"

Comment: @Abmin - Это связано с тем, что Вы пропустили значок # перед f111.

Comment: я бы посоветовал автору изучить JavaScript, прежде чем начинать изучать jQuery

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ну я как раз начал изучать JS, только вместе с JQuery. Банальная ошибка была :) Спасибо большое за помощь и совет в направлении.

Comment: @Abmin может я конечно буду не прав но все же. Код приведенный в примере по ссылке конечно жесть если честно. Если вам требуется менять некоторые данные в блоках  без перезагрузки используйте ajax. Если вам требуется скрывать все кроме активного элемента то добавляйте класс active с прописанным стилем. так же можно использовать Accordion. перебор индификаторов не выход т.к. требуется ручное исправление кода при каждом добавлении или удалении из меню.

Comment: Мне сказали чтобы сделал так, чтобы слева было вертикальное меню, а справа эти же категории только с фото, и чтобы при нажатии на категорию в левом меню или справа показать скрытый блок с контентом данной категории. Вот как это выглядит: [ссылка](http://andrend.com/photoplus/fotoposlygu.html)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По вашим данным:

```
$('#f1,#f111').click(function(){
    $('#f9,#f22,#f33,#f44,#f55,#f66,#f77,#f88').hide(0,function(){
        $('#f11').show(0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведу не совсем хорошее но простое решение вашего задания.

```
// повешу скрипт на он на случай динамического изменения страницы
$(document).on('click','.navmenu li a',function(e){
    // это спасет вас от прыжков страницы при клике на ссылку
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // забираем атрибут data 
    var blockName = $(this).data('block');
    // скрываем все в блоке контента
        $('.contentblock div').hide();
   // показываем только необходимое
        $('.'+blockName).show();
});
```

Правда прийдетеся изменить немного разметку.В атрибуте `data-block`указываем какой блок будет отображаться.

```
    <div class="navmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-block = 'druk' href="#">Широкоформатний друк</a></li>
        <li><a data-block = 'photodoc' href="#">Фото на документи</a></li>
          . .. . .. .. .  . .. 
        <li><a data-block = 'last' href="#">Колажі</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Блок с контентом должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
<div class = 'contentblock'>
   <div class = 'druk'></div>
   ..........................
   <div class = 'last'></div>
</div>
```

Решение не изящное но быстрое думаю найдете как улучшить.

Почитать о использованном можно тут:

- [e.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
- [.on](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)
- [.data()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Спасибо большое что уделили время на ответ